# Facebook posts report - Where to find it or create it?

Tags: facebook

I need a report for all 2016 posts on a Facebook page ( from January 1, 2016 to December 2016) and it should show "article author" too. Is there a way for me to get this? Thank you.

Comment: If you are looking for a built-in solution, then this question is off-topic here - for FB end user support, please consult their Help section. If you want to get data via API - then go check the documentation for Insights.